# Extract data from complex JSON in Flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm working in extract data from more complex JSON with unknown structure, its structure changes with operation ,
JSON sample link :http://afs-i.com/json.json

Kindly find my code here :   http://afs-i.com/main.dart

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
I extracted the data using PHP code, you can find result here: http://afs-i.com/json.php

Kindly this is my PHP code:

```
$arraycars=array();
$y=json_decode($x);
//  echo "<pre>";
//  var_dump($y->tree[0]->children); 
foreach ($y->tree[0]->children as $f) {
  if(isset($f->vid)){
       global $arraycars;
       $arraycars[]=$f;
   } elseif(isset($f->children)){
     if(sizeof($f->children) > 0){
        coolectcars($f->children);
     }
    }   
   }
   function coolectcars($array){
   // var_dump($array);
   foreach ($array as $f) {
     if(isset($f->vid)){
        global $arraycars;
        $arraycars[]=$f;
     } elseif(isset($f->children)){
        if(sizeof($f->children) > 0){
            coolectcars($f->children);
        }
     }  
   }
  }
  echo json_encode($arraycars);
```

**Update:2**
I have problem now with null error for this code:
The error:

```
I/flutter ( 4264): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on 
 null.
I/flutter ( 4264): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 4264): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (Children) => Null)
```

The code:

```
List<Children> cars = [];
Queue numQ = new Queue();
numQ.addAll(parsed["tree"][0]["children"]);
Iterator i = numQ.iterator;

while (i.moveNext()) {
//    print("ddddddd ${i.current}");
 if (i.current.containsKey("vid")) {
  cars.add(new Children(
      i.current['vid'], i.current['protocol'], i.current['datetime'],
      i.current['gpss']));
  } else {
  Queue numQ = new Queue();
  if (i.current["children"] != null) {
    numQ.addAll(i.current["children"]);
  //        iterate(numQ);
    List<Children> carse=[];
     carse = iterate(numQ);
     carse.forEach((data){
       cars.add(data);
     }) ;

   }
  }
 }
 cars.forEach((data) {
  print(data.toString());
 });
 List<Children> iterate(Queue numQ) {
 List<Children> cars=new List<Children>();
 Iterator i = numQ.iterator;
 while (i.moveNext()) {
 print("ddddddd ${i.current}");
 if (i.current.containsKey("vid")) {
  cars.add(new Children(
      i.current['vid'], i.current['protocol'], i.current['datetime'],
      i.current['gpss']));
  } else {
  if (i.current["children"] != null) {
    Queue numQ = new Queue();
    numQ.addAll(i.current["children"]);
    List<Children> carse=[];
    carse = iterate(numQ);
    carse.forEach((data){
      cars.add(data);
    }) ;
  }
  }
 return cars;
 } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer i reach:

```
final parsed = json.decode(response.body);
List<Children> cars = [];
Queue numQ = new Queue();
numQ.addAll(parsed["tree"][0]["children"]);
Iterator i = numQ.iterator;

while (i.moveNext()) {
  if (i.current.containsKey("vid")) {

    cars.add(new Children(
        i.current['vid'],
        i.current['datetime'],
       ));

} else {
  Queue numQ = new Queue();
  if (i.current["children"].toString() != "[]") {
    numQ.addAll(i.current["children"]);
    List<Children> carse = [];
    carse = iterate(numQ);
    carse.forEach((data) {
      cars.add(data);
    });
  }
}
}


List<Children> iterate(Queue numQ) {
List<Children> cars = new List<Children>();
Iterator i = numQ.iterator;
while (i.moveNext()) {
if (i.current.containsKey("vid")) {
  if (i.current.containsKey("vid")) {

    cars.add(new Children(
        i.current['vid'],
        i.current['datetime'],
       ));

}
 } else {
  if (i.current["children"].toString() != "[]") {
  Queue numQ = new Queue();
  if (i.current["children"].toString() != "[]") {
    numQ.addAll(i.current["children"]);
    List<Children> carse = [];
    carse = iterate(numQ);
    carse.forEach((data) {
      cars.add(data);
    });
  }
  }
}
 return cars;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A good place for convert JSON to dart [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

hats to [reddit url](https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/8e6wil/json_to_dart/)

just copy your json into the textbox and generate, it will auto generate for you.

With this, you can call `fromJson` and feed it the json, then you can also get auto complete for it

eg: usage

```
final response =
        await http.get('http://afs-i.com/json.json');

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   final Autogenerated respJson = Autogenerated.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
   print(respJson.tree[0].userId);
}
```

Comment: Good. i see that it will help, But
converter gives me multiple classes, how to feed my json to the first class (auto generated ) and get list of children objects.

Comment: fromJSON accept Map<String, dynamic> as argument, if I'm not mistaken, when you get the response, you can actually just pass in the response to that function.

Comment: can you check the updates in post that's what i need

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) to do json deserialization/ serialization. It's more elegant. You don't need to write down `fromJson` by yourself. [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) will generate deserializers / serializer for you. You can check built_value's [github](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) or [this](https://medium.com/flutter-io/some-options-for-deserializing-json-with-flutter-7481325a4450) and [this](https://aloisdeniel.github.io/flutter-json-serialization/) articles.

Comment: because of complexity i had to iterate into json with custom iteration.I used Queue but i have problem with null objects

Comment: you can find update:2 in post, now only problem with nulls

Answer (score 0):

insert this `import 'dart:convert';`
 into your widget file at top.

lets say you have your json in

```
var response
```

then

```
var jsonDecoded= json.decode(response);
```

now you can get name and user_id like this:

```
var user_id= jsonDecoded["tree"][0]["user_id"];

var name = jsonDecoded["tree"][0]["name"];
```

NOTE : I get these values from the first object (0 index). If you want values for each object , you can loop to get it.

Comment: not same structure for looping with it 
i need to loop in ( jsonDecoded["tree"][0]["children"] )

Comment: and it is array of ( object (that i need) and  at some times with new tree array )m While looping it crashes while element is new tree array

Comment: hi, how can check if value exists. Like PHP  if (isset($name['tree'])) {...}